# Detect if end digit is 1-4 or 5-9 then style `this` table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly here is my table structure

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table group-9569" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9569</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:39:00</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >John Smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9569">￥81.28</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9569">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9569">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table group-9564" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9564</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:24:10</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >Jane smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9568">￥109.69</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9568">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9568">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My `orderId` increments by one every order what I want to achieve is target the number with jquery to only detect the last number and then detect `if 0-4 else 5-9` number range then style this row red or green accordingly.

I know can convert it to a javascript number like so but I'm wondering if its just making things more complicated by turning it into a digit.

```
var number = parseInt($('.orderId').text(), 10);
alert(number)
```

the problem is that will get every order when I just need them one by one per row.

What would be the best way of going about this problem and how do I differentiate each row independently to style by end digit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just partition the list of elements, for example:

```js
var
    // all candidates
    $all = $('.orderId'),
    
    // first set
    $_04 = $all.filter(function (i, el) {
        // check criteria
        return -1 < ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'].indexOf(el.innerText.substr(-1))
    }),
    
    // all except first set
    $_59 = $all.not($_04)
;

// do stuff with both sets
$_04.closest('tr').css('background', 'red');
$_59.closest('tr').css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<table class="table group-9569" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9569</span></td>
        <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
            <span >2016-04-14 17:39:00</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >John Smith</span></td>
        <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
            <span  class="total-cost-9569">￥81.28</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
        <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
            <span  class="order-status-9569">Paid</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
        <td class="new-msg-img-9569">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table group-9564" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9564</span></td>
        <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
            <span >2016-04-14 17:24:10</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >Jane smith</span></td>
        <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
            <span  class="total-cost-9568">￥109.69</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
        <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
            <span  class="order-status-9568">Paid</span>
        </td>
        <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
        <td class="new-msg-img-9568">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Or:

```
$('.orderId').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).closest('tr').css('background', -1 < ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'].indexOf(el.innerText.substr(-1))
        ? 'red'
        : 'green'
    );
});
```

If you don't need the sets later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex `/[\d]{1}$/` to fetch the last digit of orderid,

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("orderId");
var regex = new RegExp(/[\d]{1}$/);

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
   var number = element[i].innerHTML;
   var match = regex.exec(number);
   element.setAttribute('class','class'+match[0]);
   alert('Last digit is: ' + match[0]);
}
```

You've to define different css classes for each number and name accordingly, i used `class1` etc.

Comment: This works to get the last digit but it gets it for all of them instead of per `.orderId` independently i think i need a for loop?

Comment: NooBskie - yes, you can use `jQuery.each()` function, and apply this to each found element. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/pdL83ywn/

Answer (score 0):

If you modify HTML structure a bit, you could also achieve the result with pure CSS, using attribute selector, more specifically `[attribute$="value"]`, that selects elements that end with the value. You would need to add an attribute, that describes the `order-id` to `<tr>` elements - because you cannot style whole `<tr>` by selecting child element - `<td>`. You could also add `order-id` in class attribute, but that could break things, if those `<tr>` have multiple classes.

For this html:

```
<table class="table" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-order-id="9569">
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9569</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:39:00</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >John Smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9569">￥81.28</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9569">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9569">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-order-id="9564">
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9564</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:24:10</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >Jane smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9568">￥109.69</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9568">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9568">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And these css rules

```
tr[data-order-id$="0"],tr[data-order-id$="1"],tr[data-order-id$="2"],tr[data-order-id$="3"],tr[data-order-id$="4"] {
    background-color: red;
}
tr[data-order-id$="5"],tr[data-order-id$="6"],tr[data-order-id$="7"],tr[data-order-id$="8"],tr[data-order-id$="9"] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8ngo7kh/