# Detect if price is higher or lower than 200.00 then style (this) table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Note** This question is very simalar to my previous question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620133/detect-if-end-digit-is-1-4-or-5-9-then-style-this-table-row) but I still cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Here is my current table structure:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table group-9569" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9569</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:39:00</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >John Smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9569 orderPaid">￥81.28</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9569">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9569">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table group-9564" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="order_id"  width="10%"><span class="orderId">9564</span></td>
      <td class="order_date"  width="13%">
        <span >2016-04-14 17:24:10</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_name"  width="10%"><span >Jane smith</span></td>
      <td class="order_paid"  width="5%">
        <span  class="total-cost-9568 orderPaid">￥209.69</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_shipping"  width="13%">Shipping</td>
      <td class="order_status"  width="10%">
        <span  class="order-status-9568">Paid</span>
      </td>
      <td class="order_tracking"  width="10%"></td>
      <td class="new-msg-img-9568">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to detect if `orderPaid` is higher or lower than `￥200.00` then style `this` table row

I know can convert it to a javascript number like so:

```
var orderPaid = $('.orderPaid').html();
var number = Number( orderPaid.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

The problem is that will get every order when I just need them one by one per row.

What would be the best way of going about this problem and how do I differentiate each row independently to style by pricing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate

```
$('.orderPaid').each(function(index, element) {

    var content = $(element).text();
    var number  = +content.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    console.log(number)

    if ( number > 200 ) {
        $(element).css('background', '#ff9b9b');
    }

});
```

Comment: I seem to be getting a error here `ReferenceError: orderPaid is not defined` :(

Comment: Shouldn't `+orderPaid` actually be `content`? Also, wont this code just style the span, as opposed to the whole row?

Comment: @enhzflep `content` works for me but seems to ignore the `number > 200` logic

Comment: I ended up getting it to work this post got me in the right direction i made an edit to this answer(or should i post it in my question?)

Comment: @NooBskie - nope, my bad, I edited the name of the variable without even thinking about it. Changed the answer to use the correct variable name.